# 99 Ford f150 power window

Tags: ford, f-150, power-windows

In my 1999 Ford f150 the passenger side window will let down whether it be the driver side rolls are down or the passenger side rolls it down. It will not roll back up. Could that be a wiring problem, a fuse, or possibly a window motor replacement

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, it's the window switch in the door on the driver's side. The switch on the driver's door provides power for both up and down actions to the passenger window. You can test this by pulling the switch out and jumping the power wires directly. You can also test the switch once pulled out by checking continuity using a multimeter set to read Ohms. I'm not sure if you'd need to pull the door card to get to the switch & wiring, but I don't believe so.